# Is there a way in AzureB2C to invoke a special subjourney with a custom button

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, idp, microsoft-entra-id

I'm currently facing a unique challenge with a specific user journey in my application. In this flow, users initially provide their email address or select an identity provider (IdP). A custom policy then intelligently directs users to the appropriate view – steering them towards the password view if they already possess a B2C account or guiding them to the signup page if they are new.

Now, my objective is to enhance the signup view by introducing a distinctive button labeled "Already have an account? Click here". When users click on this button, the aim is to seamlessly transition them to a subjourney dedicated to linking their social account to their existing B2C account.

The key question is: Is it feasible to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar. I posted on this [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/changing-the-federation-button-into-a-link-in-azure-ad-b2c-f83356562c1e).

Essentially, you add another "ClaimsProviderSelection" to handle this case.

Another example of this is the embedded password reset [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset).

Comment: appreciate the suggestion regarding ClaimsProviderSelection. Is it possible to incorporate the button directly into the user information input view instead of a dedicated "select this or this" view? I aim to include a small "Link Account here" button in my signUp view, where the user provides all their information.

Comment: Additionally, I experimented with a secondary "CombinedSignInAndSignUp" type within my Orchestration Steps. The button appears when using "api.signuporsignin" as the ContentDefinitionReferenceId  (or unifiedssp as DataUri); however, only the initial 2 claims are visible for the user to complete, rather than all of them (10 in total).

Comment: Yes, it only works with unified. It has to be a button or a link on its own.

Comment: But there is no way to show all 10 claims is it?

Comment: Not in the login screen, no.